# Track key strokes in Word Document hosted in Browser Control in a WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, webbrowser-control

I am using word application host in browser. According to my application I want to use the selected text from the hosted document using any key press like if I press <kbd>s</kbd> then the selected text in the document will be return.

The problem is when I press any key in document it replace the word i have selected in the document and set the value which key I am pressing.

For example `"Hi how are you"` is selected in document and when I press <kbd>s</kbd> key it becomes `"s"` instead of returning `"Hi how are you"`.

How can I track which key is pressed and get the selected text from the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok no body is giving the answer i am gone do this. I have done with the Key tracking on the windows. genraly its not posible to capture into office app that which key has been pressed.
 so  i found the answer is to use keyboard hook into your application which track all key input send to windows by keyboard. the code sample is below

This http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx sample help me to find the key stork which i passed to application.